# RCB ANOVA: Degrees of Freedom wrong?

Tags: r, anova, degrees-of-freedom

I am running an ANOVA analysis on randomised complete block RCB design:

- 7 Genotypes
- 6 Blocks
- Ratings

The model I am fitting is:

```
lm(Ratings ~ GENOTYPE + BLOCK + BLOCK * GENOTYPE)
```

Here is some of the structure of my data in R:

```
'data.frame':   448 obs. of  13 variables: 
$ GENOTYPE : Factor w/ 7 levels "EVEREST","JAGALENE",..: 7 5 6 6 6 2 6 6 6 3 
$ BLOCK    : Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: NA 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

This is the ANOVA output:

[image]

Shouldn't it be Factor A: Genotype-1 and Factor B: Block-1?

I have them set as factors but can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my code. (My issue is with the Genotype factor)

Comment: Are you asking why the Genotype Df isn't 6 instead of 5? If so, edit your question to say that. In that case, I would suggest looking at summary(fit) and see which level is missing and just look at the rows with that level for Genotype. If there is missing data, that would answer your question.

Comment: Hi HStamper: So you are saying that maybe because there is missing data for one of the genotypes that's why the genotype is 5 instead of 6 right??

Comment: That would be the first thing to check. Also, if the factor was modified, it can have levels that aren't present any more.

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph or screenshot (see 
[here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)).